# Expand/Collapse Text in HTML - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a 'See More' (expand) and 'See Less' (collapse) javascript code working. I will loop through and call this javascript code on each class instance in the HTML.

This actually works for the first time it appears on the page. I put in Console.logs to see that it works correctly. i.e. each time I click 'See More' the console will print 'Expand/Collapse' once.

However, each additional instance of the device (on another piece of text on the page), it won't expand at all.

What happens is that in the second instance, the console prints - "Expand, Collapse". So it actually does both instantaneously (which means it doesn't expand at all).

In the third, it prints - "Expand, Collapse, Expand, Collapse, Expand, Collapse". Almost like exponential growth... Any ideas?

```
function showMoreLess(element) {
var showChar = 150;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "See More";
var lesstext = "See Less";
var content = $(element).html();
if (content.length > showChar) {
    var show_content = content.substr(0, showChar);
    var hide_content = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
    var html = show_content 
                + '<span class="moreelipses">' 
                + ellipsestext
                + '</span><span class="remaining-content"><span>' 
                + hide_content + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' 
                + moretext 
                + '</a></span>';
    $(element).html(html);
}

$(".morelink").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html("See More");
        console.log("Collapse") // "Collapse" appears in console
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html("See Less");
        console.log("Expand") // "Expand" appears in console
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();

    return false;
});
```

}

This is the JQuery code that loops through each class:

```
$(function () {
    $.each($(".limitedTextSpace"), function(index, value) {
        showMoreLess(value);
    });
});
```

EDIT:

I followed Roberto Linares' format and recreated the function like so:

```
function showMoreLess(element) {
var showChar = 150;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "See More";
var lesstext = "See Less";
var content = $(element).html();
if (content.length > showChar) {
    var show_content = content.substr(0, showChar);
    var hide_content = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
    var html = '<span class="collapsed">' + show_content 
                + ellipsestext
                + '</span><span class="expanded">'
                + content
                + '</span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="collapsed">'
                + moretext
                + '</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="expanded">' 
                + lesstext
                + '</a>'
    $(element).html(html);
}
```

}

Then I made slight changes to the other looping function as well:

```
    $(function () {
    $.each($(".limitedTextSpace"), function(index, value) {
        showMoreLess(value);
    });

    $(".expanded").hide();
    $(".expanded, .collapsed").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().children(".expanded, .collapsed").toggle();
    });
});
```

However, now there is the issue with when there are breaks in the text. The code interprets each paragraph of the same text as a different expand/collapse instances - meaning instead of one expand/collapse for a block of text, there is multiple for each paragraph.

Comment: You tagged boostrap? Bootstrap has a built in collapse http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't expand at all the second and following times because you already lost the complete content when you replaced it with the collapsed content. This happens because you never 'save' temporally the complete content elsewhere so you can place it back when the expand link is clicked.

I would recommend you to change your javascript logic to place in the HTML both collapsed an expanded content and toggle its visibility through the links.

Example:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="expanded">Expanded HTML content</span>
        <span class="collapsed">Collap...</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="collapsed">Expand</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="expanded">Collapse</a>
    </li>
     <li>
        <span class="expanded">Expanded HTML content</span>
        <span class="collapsed">Collap...</span>
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="collapsed">Expand</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="expanded">Collapse</a>
    </li>
     <li>
        <span class="expanded">Expanded HTML content</span>
        <span class="collapsed">Collap...</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="collapsed">Expand</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="expanded">Collapse</a>
    </li>
     <li>
        <span class="expanded">Expanded HTML content</span>
        <span class="collapsed">Collap...</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="collapsed">Expand</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="expanded">Collapse</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".collapsed").hide();

    $(".expanded, .collapsed").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().children(".expanded, .collapsed").toggle();
    });
});
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/susxK/

Comment: Thanks Roberto, that followed that same format and it fixed it for me. However there is a new issue such that when there are breaks in the block of text, it interprets each paragraph as a separate piece of text. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out this other fiddle I made with you exact javascript: [http://jsfiddle.net/uQLTU/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/uQLTU/1/) It appears to work with all kinds of block elements in my sample HTML. Maybe if you post some of your HTML I can figure out why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work! Don't know what the heck happened. Thanks man!

Comment: I made a couple of changes such that you can only expand/collapse on clicking 'seemore/seeless' and not the whole span element. But yeah, all works well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Roberto Linares, I fixed the code to work like so:

```
function showMoreLess(element) {
var showChar = 256;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "See More";
var lesstext = "See Less";
var content = $(element).html();
if (content.length > showChar) {
    var show_content = content.substr(0, showChar);
    var hide_content = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
    var html = '<span class="collapsed">' + show_content 
                + ellipsestext
                + '</span><span class="expanded">'
                + content
                + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="collapsed moretext">'
                + moretext
                + '</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="expanded lesstext">' 
                + lesstext
                + '</a>'
    $(element).html(html);
}
```

}

And in a separate function on when document is ready:

```
$(function () { // When page is loaded, run showMoreLess(value) on each instance of limitedTextSpace classes
$.each($(".limitedTextSpace"), function(index, value) {
    showMoreLess(value); 
});
$(".expanded").hide();
$(".moretext, .lesstext").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children(".expanded, .collapsed").toggle();
});
```

});